# Group items by range, while the time must still comply with time

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Grouping items by scope and time must still be satisfactory
I tried many ways, and what I achieved was not what I expected

I have array

```
const data = [
    {
        detected_time: 1,
        estimated_stay_time: 300,
        extension_window: 100000
    },
    {
        detected_time: 2,
        estimated_stay_time: 330000,
        extension_window: 100000
    },
    {
        detected_time: 3,
        estimated_stay_time: 130000,
        extension_window: 100000
    },
    {
        detected_time: 4,
        estimated_stay_time: 150000,
        extension_window: 100000
    },
    {
        detected_time: 5,
        estimated_stay_time: 3000,
        extension_window: 100000
    },
    {
        detected_time: 6,
        estimated_stay_time: 591988,
        extension_window: 100000
    },
    {
        detected_time: 7,
        estimated_stay_time: 663913,
        extension_window: 100000
    }
];
```

Now I want to group the items by field estimated_stay_time and the grouping range is 100000 but still comply with the order of field detected_time

For example, if the next item has an estimated_stay_time field larger than the specified range, it will be grouped from there.

And the range must go forward, not backward

The output I desire is

```json
[
    [
        {
            detected_time: 1,
            estimated_stay_time: 300,
            extension_window: 100000
        },
    ],
    [
        {
            detected_time: 2,
            estimated_stay_time: 330000,
            extension_window: 100000
        },
    ],
    [
        {
            detected_time: 3,
            estimated_stay_time: 130000,
            extension_window: 100000
        },
        {
            detected_time: 4,
            estimated_stay_time: 150000,
            extension_window: 100000
        },
    ],
    [
        {
            detected_time: 5,
            estimated_stay_time: 3000,
            extension_window: 100000
        },
    ],
    [
        {
            detected_time: 6,
            estimated_stay_time: 591988,
            extension_window: 100000
        },
        {
            detected_time: 7,
            estimated_stay_time: 663913,
            extension_window: 100000
        }
    ]
]
```

Comment: Please show us your attempt at solving this.

Comment: Not 100% sure about your grouping rules. So if you have an element with an `estimated_staytime` of `x` and an `extension_window` of `y`, you want all elements with an `estimated_staytime` between `x` and `x+y` to be grouped together? Does the `extension_window` of the grouped elements also play a role, or is it just the extension window of the first element in the group?

Comment: Imagine the following example `{st: 10, ew: 5}, {st, 11, ew 3}, {st: 14, ew 7}, {st: 16, ew: 3}`  will your grouping consist only of the first three elements (ie `st in 10 .. 15`) or does the `ew: 7` or the third element expand the the window of elements to be included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build a delta and check with the interval. If outside take a new group.

```js
const
    data = [{ detected_time: 1, estimated_stay_time: 300, extension_window: 100000 }, { detected_time: 2, estimated_stay_time: 330000, extension_window: 100000 }, { detected_time: 3, estimated_stay_time: 130000, extension_window: 100000 }, { detected_time: 4, estimated_stay_time: 150000, extension_window: 100000 }, { detected_time: 5, estimated_stay_time: 3000, extension_window: 100000 }, { detected_time: 6, estimated_stay_time: 591988, extension_window: 100000 }, { detected_time: 7, estimated_stay_time: 663913, extension_window: 100000 }],
    result = data.reduce((r, o, i, a) => {
        const delta = o.estimated_stay_time - (a[i - 1]?.estimated_stay_time ?? 0);

        if (!i || delta < 0 || delta > o.extension_window) r.push([o]);
        else r.at(-1).push(o);
        
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what I needed

Comment: Hello NinaSchlz,

My problem is that there is a slight change in the group according to the extentions_window scope, they must have the same zone_id. With your code, I don't know how I can reuse them.